# SQL Join grouping for tree-like result

Tags: mysql, sql, join, tree, grouping

First of all, I'd like to say that I've done a bit of research but I still wasn't able to get a clear answer at my question. Please feel free to give me links to places I might have missed.

I've long been using a simple `.json` file (written by hand) containing all data for my website. This was parsed by JQuery, which then build the whole page from it (see [my personnal webpage](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/hadrien.croubois)). For many reasons (ease of editing, having a working webpage even when javascript is blocked) I'd like to build a PHP/MySQL version of it.

My issue is with translating the tree structure of my `.json` file to a single SQL Query.

My database has tables for `pages`, `articles` and `citations` with each one having an ID as well as foreign key (to there father) in a one-to-many model.

```
        Pages
----------------------
Page_ID |  Page_Title
----------------------
   0    |    About
   2    |    Work
   3    | Publication


             Articles
------------------------------------
Article_ID | Page_ID | Article_Title
------------------------------------
     0     |   0     |   About me
     1     |   3     |   Articles


              Citations
-----------------------------------------
Citation_ID | Article_ID | Citation_Title
-----------------------------------------
     0      |     3      |  My fst quote
     1      |     3      |  My snd quote
```

So far I've build the following query :

```
SELECT * FROM pages
LEFT OUTER JOIN articles
  ON pages.Page_ID = articles.Page_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN citations
  ON articles.Article_ID = citations.Article_ID
ORDER BY pages.Page_Order IS NULL, pages.Page_Order ASC
```

Yet this makes me getting a multiple time elements which have multiple sons / grand sons.

Is there a better way to represent a tree ? I tried looking at `GROUP BY` but that only gives me the first child.

Comment: You may want to provide sample data and the expected result.

Comment: I've added some exemple data. As for the expected results, I don't know how they should be (that is the point of my question)

Comment: Now with this data in mind please explain why exactly your query does not satisfy your needs and what you'd like to get instead.

Comment: In this case, where I have 2 citations for the same article, I get 1 line per citation, with all the article/page elements filled.

That sound like a lot of data duplicated, where having them only once whould be enough. Therefore i'm asking if there is a way to have a more "tree-like" answer which would eliminate some of this duplicated data

Comment: Have a look at [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). It can flatten your data as long as you do not mind getting it back as a string.

Comment: You may want to take a look into Bill Karwin's "SQL Antipatterns" book (online pdf could be found by google's search) - chapter 3 "Naive trees".

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to fetch all the data to build a tree structure, there is no better way to do that than the above query. You should not be concerned with duplication issues, since you have to parse the data anyway, and the fact that you want to load all the data from the data base at once suggests that your database is not large at all. Just extend the order by clause by adding article_id and citation_id in that order, to make the whole data set sorted properly so you can just pass through it and build the tree.

That said, you can get rid of duplication issues by issuing multiple queries, first getting all the pages, then all the articles for each page, then all the citations for each article. However that would likely be slower because you would have lots of database round trips. For this kind of solution to be effective, you'd have to tweak user interface to load the data dynamically, as it's requested. For example, you show a list of pages only, and when a user clicks on a single page a query is executed that fetches articles for that single page.